# HTML Scraping using R for simple table

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table on this website : https://www.kimiafarma.co.id/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=193&Itemid=353&lang=id

I've tried using :

[image]

I would like to scrape the data from that table and put it in an excel file, but I'm quite new to R programming and web scraping. I would appreciate if someone could explain what I need to do step by step.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Such how-to's are available in the web, see e.g. [r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/).

Comment: Please don't post code as images share them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.kimiafarma.co.id/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=193&Itemid=353&lang=id'

data <- url %>%
          read_html() %>%
          html_nodes('table') %>%
          .[[1]] %>%
          html_table()
```

To write data as csv, you can use `write.csv`

```
write.csv(data, 'data.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```